# NSCursor memory leak (currentSystemCursor)

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory-leaks

I am facing a strange problem right now. At some point in my program I capture the mouse cursor of the system in OSX. For this I do:

```
NSCursor *cursor = [NSCursor currentSystemCursor];
```

I have removed everything else that works with the cursor to test the issue. But this single call gives me a huge memory leak (the cursor is captured multiple times per second). Its about 50MB/s memory leak.

Do I have to free the cursor somehow? According to the docs ( https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nscursor/1533611-currentsystemcursor?language=objc ) if I understand it correctly `currentSystemCursor` will give me a copy of the system cursor. But it does not state anything about if I need to release the memory or not.

Currently my program does not use ARC.

Comment: How did you find this leak? Did you try the memory graph view in Xcode to see? Can you give us a minimal code sample that exhibits the leak? Is your program using threading in any way? Or are you running a loop to repeatedly capture the cursor?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue by now. The problem was that the cursor got grabbed on a different thread that was created using the `pthread` library. I have implemented an autoreleasepool on the thread and the memory leak is gone now.